# How to extract lines with n number of tabs? unix

Tags: bash, unix, csv

I have a tab-delimited file as such:

```
xyz
abc foo bar
hello   world
lmn opq rst
```

I want to extract lines with exactly 3 tabs and achieve:

```
abc foo bar
lmn opq rst
```

I have been doing it with python:

```
fout = ('outfile', 'w')
with open('infile', 'r') as fin:
  for line in fin:
    if line.count('\t') == 3:
      print>>fout, line
```

**What is the unix/bash way to do it?**

Comment: The output you showed is seperated by spaces ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` with field separator as `\t` (tab):

```
awk -F '\t' 'NF==3' file
abc foo bar
lmn opq rst
```

`NF==3` condition will only print lines with exactly 3 fields (2 tabs).